# 1 x male micro USB to 2 x female

Tags: usb

I have an Android tablet and have it fixed up onto an external keyboard via a micro USB cable. But whilst using the tablet I would also like to be charging it. So would like to know if there is such a cable that splits from one male to two female micro USBs. I can't seem to find one anywhere. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

That's an excessively non-standard cable. But "Micro USB Host OTG Cable w/USB power" is what you want. You need a cable for OTG Host mode, and charging. That one will give you a micro male to plug into the tablet, a micro mini for charging, and a usb A female. You might need a usb a female to micro female adaptor.

Well, it might not work though. http://mehrvarz.github.com/usb-otg-power-nexus7/ points out that the Nexus 7, the plain vanilla, pure android and no manufacturer bs tablet, needs two driver/kernel patches for USB Host Mode AND Charging to work at the same time.

Comment: Sounds like I will have to charge seperately for the foreseeable future. Thank you Passerby for taking the time to try and help me.

Comment: @Kaz, if your tablet has an active modding community, they might be willing/able to port over the nexus 7 patch. Check slatedroid or xda-developers websites.

Comment: Ok Passerby. Thank you for your help. Will give that a go. :-)

Comment: @Kaz. As an alternative, have you considered getting a Bluetooth keyboard? Saves the need for any patching.

Answer (score 1):

The cable you are looking for does not exist. And a USB compliant host device won't be charged even if you provide power through an homebrew cable. The otg Y cables you will find are meant to power the device you attach and not the host, so they won't help much. You can use them in order to lighten the load on the host though.

Comment: The cable does exist.

Comment: Well then that's not USB compliant and can possibly damage the host. We are not speaking of a Y cable commonly used to connect external HDDs.

Comment: Those are NOT USB Compliant either. Every cable connected to a USB host must A) Enumerate and B) USB compliant device must not draw more than 1 power block (100ma) without requesting more NOR draw more than 5 power blocks (500ma). Those Y cables break all of that. And even then, are used for devices that draw more than 1A. Aftermarket hacking, not a USB specification friendly business.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I did not think of that. Maybe some devices with Y cables have a custom USB connector with two pins for the 5V, one for the host and one for the power supply. But it's quite unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

USB connections are NOT designed to be used as a "Y" connection. You will not likely find the type of device that you are looking for. Certainly do not try to cobble up something on your own unless you 101% understand the internal circuitry in both the existing device and its charger.

Is such a device feasible? It may be if it was incorporated as a feature into the charging unit itself. Short that stay away from a hacked solution.